# Split a file into two but preserve lines

Tags: python, bash

I am struggling with splitting a text file into two.

For example this splits the file into two but if there is an uneven number of lines it creates a third file:

```
for line in infile:
        count_lines += 1
lines_per_file = int(count_lines / 2)
        subprocess.call(['split', '-l', str(lines_per_file), '--numeric-suffixes', infile, chunk_destination])
```

While this splits the file into two but cuts lines in half:

```
subprocess.call(['split', '-n', '1/2', '--numeric-suffixes', infile, chunk_destination])
```

Is there a relatively simple way of splitting a file into two with Python or Bash that will add the extra line (if number of lines is uneven) into one of the two existing files instead of making a third **or** splitting into two files but preserving lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually newer version of split has an option to preserve lines:

CHUNKS may be:
N       split into N files based on size of input
K/N     output Kth of N to stdout
l/N     split into N files without splitting lines/records
l/K/N   output Kth of N to stdout without splitting lines/records
r/N     like 'l' but use round robin distribution
r/K/N   likewise but only output Kth of N to stdout

so this works:

`subprocess.call(['split', '-n', 'l/2', '--numeric-suffixes', infile, chunk_destination])`